# LD1117 / SO-8 heat dissipation

Tags: voltage-regulator, surface-mount

I'm new to SMD, and was thinking of using the SO-8 package for the LD1117V33, which I'm using to step down from 6v to 3.3v, running at about 50mA max.

I was noticing that while the other packages offer heat sync tabs, the SO-8 just has the center four pins (2,3,6,7) all as Vout. Should these just be connected to one large pad running under the IC, or just use a normal SO-8 footprint? I didn't see any specific footprint information for the SO-8 in the datasheet.

Please note that I'm not married to the LM1117; if there's a more suitable regulator for the given load, please let me know.

Comment: If you're really trying to minimize footprint, there are many regulators in SOT23 or TSOP5 packages that you might consider. They are typically ~150mA, and not all of them handle 6Vin, but there are certainly some that should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, well- we're talking about (6VDC-3.3VDC)* 50mA = 135mW, which should be just fine for an SO-8**. There are SOT-223 versions of the '1117 available if you want as well as larger SMT packages. It's a common LDO regulator- lots of sources, so a reasonable choice- maybe the SOT-223 is even more common.

** Thermal resistance junction-to-ambient is stated to be about about 55K/W, so you'd have only about 7°C rise. Barely warm. Note carefully that that's based on some standard layout, laminate and copper thickness which you'd have to dig for- but probably not the absolute minimum amount of copper! - datasheets do things like that).

It costs little to nothing to extend the four Vout connections under the package and maybe spread them out on either side of the chip, but it's not really necessary in this case.

Edit: Note that the SO8 (in ST's standard footprint) is better thermally, by 2:1, though either would work in this case. Also the '1117 is kind of a semi-LDO, there are much lower dropout parts available, but that is not a factor in this case- you have plenty of voltage, so there is no advantage in using a lower dropout part.

Thermal performance of SMT parts is heavily influenced by the footprint and copper thickness and other factors outside the chip, so one should be careful when running close to the limits, but this application is a slam-dunk (assuming nothing pathological like extremely hot environment or having to operate in a vacuum).

Comment: I was looking for the smallest footprint, but the SOT-223 and SO-8 are pretty close anyway.

Comment: The SO8 is better thermally, by 2:1 in ST's standard footprint.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if "minimum footprint" is the criteria, a through-hole stand-up regulator in TO92 has less footprint than an SO-8 (albeit with worse thermal resistance (200K/W for L78L - so 27°C rise for 135 mW), though the SO-8 needs 6 sq cm of copper to get 55K/W thermal resistance per [the datasheet I looked at](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/389/CD00000446-355303.pdf) (L78L, not an LM1117, which does seem vague on that point.) Even a TO-220 (standing up) takes up less board real-estate, so long as you don't need to board mount a heat sink (which you should not for your load), and that has slightly better "bare" thermal resistance (50K/W) with no need for thermal real estate on the board.

They do require more vertical real-estate, and you may have an unstated assumption that ONLY SMD parts are to be considered here. In general, yes, more copper is better for heat dissipation from SMD packages. Use the regular soldermask and as much copper as you can give them, with vias if feasible.

The linked LD78L datasheet mentions in two footnotes on Page 5:

> Our SO-8 package used for voltage regulators is modified internally to have pins 2, 3, 6 and 7 electrically communed to the die attach flag. This particular frame decreases the total thermal resistance of the package and increases its ability to dissipate power when an appropriate area of copper on the printed circuit board is available for heat-sinking. The external dimensions are the same as for the standard SO-8.

And:

> Considering 6 cm2 of copper Board heat-sink.

Since your regulator is configured the same way, despite not having that language (at least that I can find) I'm going to suspect it's similar.